# Apparent time-travelling via python's multiprocessing module: surely I've done something wrong

Tags: python, r, multiprocessing

I use python for video-game-like experiments in cognitive science. I'm testing out a device that detects eye movements via [EOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOG), and this device talks to the computer via USB. To ensure that data is being continuously read from the USB while the experiment does other things (like changing the display, etc), I thought I'd use the multiprocessing module (with a multicore computer of course), put the USB reading work in a separate worker process, and use a queue to tell that worker when events of interest occur in the experiment. However, I've encountered some strange behaviour such that even when there is 1 second between the enqueuing of 2 different messages to the worker, when I look at the worker's output at the end, it seems to have received the second almost immediately after the first. Surely I've coded something awry, but I can't see what, so I'd very much appreciate help anyone can provide.

I've attempted to strip down my code to a minimal example demonstrating this behaviour. If you go to this gist:

https://gist.github.com/914070

you will find "multiprocessing_timetravel.py", which codes the example, and "analysis.R", which analyzes the "temp.txt" file that results from running "multiprocessing_timetravel.py". "analysis.R" is written in R and requires you have the plyr library installed, but I've also included example of the analysis output in the "analysis_results.txt" file at the gist.

Comment: just a guess, but your busy-wait routine could be part of the problem.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: thanks for the suggestion, but replacing all instances of wait(...) with time.sleep(1) yields the same behaviour.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that module, so your code looks like gibberish to me, but if the queue-writer and queue-reader are on separate threads writing to the same queue, you have no way of knowing when the writer will give up the lock to the queue *(remember, the writer could be interrupted for an arbitrary amount of time while holding the lock)*, so the only way to really know when the data came into the writer is to include the *time received* as part of the object you're queueing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I solved it and it turned out to be much simpler than I expected. There were 5 events per "trial" and the final event triggered a write of data to the HD. If this final write takes a long time, the worker may not grab the next trial's first event until the second event has already been put into the queue. When this happens, the first event lasts (to the worker's eyes) for only one of its loops before it encounters the second event. I'll have to either figure out a faster way to write out the data or leave the data in memory until a break in the experiment permits a long write.

Answer (score 1):

Despite working with multiprocessing, your queue still uses synchronization objects (two locks and a semaphore) and the put method spawns another thread (based on the 2.7 source). So GIL contention (and other fun stuff) may come into play, as suggested by BlueRaja. You can try playing with [sys.checkinterval](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval) and see if decreasing it also decreases the observed discrepancy, although you don't want to run normally in that condition.

Note that, if your USB reading code drops the GIL (e.g. ctypes code, or a Python extension module designed to drop the GIL), you do get true multithreading, and a threaded approach might be more productive than using multiprocessing.